# How can I create a branch from a existing branch in cvs

Tags: cvs

I have one branch named "Gem36" but I want to create another branch named "RM_Gem36" from the existing branch. How can I do that in CVS?

Is there any other way to create new branch "RM_Gem36"from existing branch without checking out the "Gem36" branch?

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout Gem36 and create new branch with the following command:

`$ cvs tag -b RM_Gem36`

Or you can try to do this without checking out:

`$ cvs  rtag -b -r Gem36 -- RM_Gem36 "module_name"`

Comment: Without checking out the branch Gem36 is it possible to create the new branch

Comment: @Danil: You need to specify the name of the module you're tagging, when using the `rtag`-command.

Comment: In the command :-cvs rtag -b -r Gem36 -- RM_Gem36 why --RM_Gem36 is used and this command failed with that -- option .pls suggest

Comment: @maitree: there should be a space between the `--` and the tag name. Actually, the `--` is completely optional: It is only needed in some corner cases where CVS would otherwise not be able to tell whether the next argument is an option parameter or a file/module/tag. And of course you should specify the name of the module you're `rtag`ging (see Danil's revised answer).